How to user form reference for nested control using ng-template
I have created ng-form template to render multilevel reactive forms,
To print the nested controls I want to render it using some ng-template if the condition is true.
I know for one level of hierarchy passing form as context works, but how to do it
for deeply nested control, should whole form context be passed?
Stackblitz issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-g7ndft?file=src%2Fmain.ts
This error is thrown
ERROR Error: NG01050: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
      directive and pass it to an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

    Example:

    
  <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
  </div>

  In your class:

  this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl()
  });
    at controlParentException (@angular_forms.js?v=c471ac44:1182:10)```
  

